When reducing data set size, shall I keep total_epochs or total_step_count constant?
Background: I've started two trainings from scratch for the same total_step_count. Trainings were identical except that in one of them I subsampled only 50% of the dataset.
My assumption was that most metrics scale with epoch_idx - e.g. after the model has seen a data item five times, it should have remembered it. However, at least some metrics rather scale with step_idx - suggesting that it's more relevant that a certain number of optimization steps are performed rather than how often individual items are seen.
Is this a general experience? Are there any guidelines on how (optimal) training length should scale with dataset size?
